# Get value of selectbox with JsHelper in CakePHP

Tags: javascript, cakephp, helper, drop-down-menu

I have a select box, and I want to use it to Ajax-update some other content on the page. So I have bound an event handler using the JsHelper (jQuery) like so:

```
<?php
echo $this->Form->select('car', $cars);
$this->Js->get("#car");
$this->Js->event('change', $this->Js->request(array(
    'controller'  => 'cars',
    'action'      => 'view', 
    ???,
    array('async' => true, 'update' => '#car-view', 'evalScripts'  => true),
    true
));
?>
```

But how can I get the value of the select box to send as an argument to the cars controller (at "???" in the code above)?

I could do everything in javascript, but is there any way to do this in cake?

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, I struggled with this a while back. I couldn't find anything that worked, so I ended up just going the straight javascript route.

Comment: I've been trying to figure this out for ages too and still haven't come accross anything useful.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for this:

```
$this->Js->get('#selectbboxid1')->event('change', 
        $this->Js->request(array(
            'action' => 'function'), array(
                /*'before' => 'showLoader();',
                'success' => 'hideLoader();',*/
                'update' => '#selectboxid2',
                'dataExpression'=>TRUE, 
                'method'=>'POST',
                'async'=>TRUE,
                'data' => $js->serializeForm(array('isForm' => TRUE, 'inline' => TRUE))  )));
```